# Samsung Galaxy S3 spelling checker

Tags: android, galaxy, samsung-mobile, spelling

A user has reported that, when he has the spelling checked enabled on his Samsung Galaxy S3, he can't do some actions with my app.

I've asked more users to do this, and it only happens with Samsung Galaxy S3.

Is there any way to fix this issue? Is the SGS3 spelling checker different from other spelling checkers?